# Split array into N roughly equal parts in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to split an array into `N` *roughly* equal parts (number of parts given). I managed to do it if the remainder of `array.length % numParts == 0` but I can't find a way to do it otherwise.

May anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: When asking coding questions, post your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it'd be helpful if you share your current code when asking a question, so it's easier to get a fitting solution for you.

So, conceptually, what I guess you want to do is create `N` buckets, and assign each item to the correct bucket. I wrote you a function using a simple `int[]`, but the point is mostly the algorithm, not the specific implementation I used.

```java
public static int[][] divideIntoSubArrays(int N, int[] array) {
    // Each bucket has the size (which is not a whole number)
    float bucketSize = array.length / (float) N;
    System.out.println("Bucket size is "+ bucketSize);

    int[][] result = new int[N][];

    for (int currentBucket = 0; currentBucket < N; currentBucket++) {
        // In this bucket are all the values from currentBucket * bucketSize up to currentBucket * bucketSize + bucketSize
        result[currentBucket] = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, (int) Math.ceil(currentBucket * bucketSize), (int) Math.ceil(currentBucket * bucketSize + bucketSize));
    }

    return result;
}
```

In short, it first calculates the `bucketSize`, then takes the correct subArray for each bucket, using the bucket size and index.

Some example outputs from this function:

```
3, {1,2,3,4,5,6} => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
3, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
2, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
5, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} => [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [6], [7]]
```

By taking the `ceil` of the index items get pushed into the proper buckets.